# Why XAML Width="Auto" does not work for me?

Tags: xaml

I started maintenance on some poorly written XAMLs. I am relatively new to XAML.

One thing I need is - grid columns should automatically adjust their width per the text contents.

The MSDN documentation on GridViewColumn.Width says - set it to Auto to enable auto-sizing behavior. However even though the code reads as follows, column widths remain the same irrespective of the content text.

```
<ListView.View>
<GridView>
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lstColName" Width="200">Name</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lstColPath" Width="Auto">Path</GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `GridView` recalculates column content sizes only when the template or internal column collection change, that's why `Width="Auto"` only works on loading the `GridView`.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120106075754/http://www.leghumped.com:80/blog/2009/03/11/wpf-gridview-column-width-calculator/)'s an article about a possible approach to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Auto does work fine as below.

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Spoons" Width="Auto">

                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This David Hanson blog post contains another solution.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120107103054/http://www.ontheblog.net/CMS/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/37/Default.aspx)